# "concession" in "concession of something due"

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage

I have trouble construing the meaning of this sentence:

> "claim implies a demand for the delivery or concession of something
>   due as one's own or one's right" [[from Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary]]

My understand is:

- "the delivery" perhaps means "something delivered to you, like a
  package etc"
- "concession" is a "right"  as in "have the right to do something".
- "concession of something due" means "some right you deserve"

However, I can not find the meaning "right" for "concession" in dictionaries.

Comment: The word that is causing you confusion here is *concession*. It is not the same thing as a *right* or *entitlement*, but something that is awarded *ex gratia*. But it can be subject of a claim. E.g. the work force claimed the *concession* of a Christmas bonus. It is something that is granted, not as a right, but in response to a demand.

Comment: @WS2 - I'd like to think you can set the questioner's mind fully at rest by supplying the dictionary reference/definition he desires which would back up your explanation. Otherwise: no cigar for you either; a tiny fag if you're lucky.  ;)

Comment: @ErikKowal Underlying all dictionary definitions of *claim* is some notion of *entitlement*. That much I will concede. But it is used so much, in an everyday sense, with the idea of *concession* that that cannot be ignored. And it was central to the OP's question. This is an extract, for example, from the website of *the Camping and Caravanning Club* *To claim Age Concession present your proof of age - driving licence, birth certificate etc. at any Club Site.*. Hence people do talk about *claiming a concession*.

Comment: @WS2 The example "Age Concession" is typical British English, but "Merriam-Webster" is an American dictionary. "concession" in "Age Concession" means "a special price which is lower than the usual price and which is often given to old people, students, and the unemployed. " (from Collins COBUILD Dictionary). It is extraneous to the question being discussed.

Comment: @JamesKing You may be interested in the dialogue on my more recent question on 'Can one claim a concession'?

Answer (score 3):

[concession](https://www.google.com/search?q=concession&oq=concession&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4403j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) (noun): a thing that is granted, especially in response to demands; a thing conceded;
"the strikers returned to work having won some concessions"

verb: concede.

synonyms:   compromise, allowance, exception;
"the government made several concessions".

So we may say the word "claim" implies a demand for either the delivery or concession of something due as one's own or one's right

Comment: If "concession" means "COMPROMISE" as in "the government made several concessions over welfare cuts", then How can someone "claim a concession"? The right verb shoule be "grant , make, offer, win/obtain/gain".

Comment: @James King, claim is here being used in the sense of 'taking possession'.

Comment: Concession is ***not*** being used in the sense of a compromise, but in the sense of the act of conceding. [Concede](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concede): (1) to grant as a right or privilege. I believe they inserted this to take care of the case where *delivery* doesn't apply because the thing being claimed is not tangible. You can claim your right to be tried before your peers; this right cannot be delivered, but it can be conceded to you.

Answer (score 0):

A search for your query sentence led me to M-W's [entry for ***demand***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demand).

> 'Claim' implies a demand for the delivery or concession of something due as one's own or one's right

can be paraphrased as follows:

'Claim' implies that something is being demanded because it either a) is the property of the person claiming it, or b) they have a right to it.

Comment: But you have left out the all-important bit about *concession*, which is clearly the word that is causing confusion to the OP. You can also 'claim' a *concession*, just as much as you can claim a *right* or an *entitlement*. No cigar for you today!